# Change the integration order of $\int^2_{-6} \int^{2-x}_{\frac{x^2}{4}- 1}f(x, y) \, dy\,dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

This is a question from sample exam that I'm trying to solve but having difficults.

> Change the integration order of the integral:

$$\int^2_{-6} \int^{2-x}_{\frac{x^2}{4}- 1}f(x, y) \, dy\,dx$$.

$\implies -6 \le x \le 2, $

$\frac{x^2}{4} + 1 \le y \le 2 - x.$

I started to graph it but I stuck in graphing $y$.

How can I change the integration order of the this integral?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably mean $\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: @GitGud I mean $dx dy$, I believe this is why I should change the order of the integration to $dy dx$.

Comment: Nope, it simply doesn't make sense as it is.

Comment: @GitGud This is originally written as: $$\int^2_{-6} \, dx\int^{2-x}_{\frac{x^2}{4}- 1}f(x, y) \,dy$$. Isn't it the same?

Comment: Apart from the fact that I prefer "Nope" to "Nop", I fully agree with @GitGud last comment.

Comment: @GitGud Looked again, my bad. you are right, I edited my post.

Comment: To change the order of integration, you need to break the integration region into 2 pieces.  Can you see why?

Comment: @Did Comment duly corrected.

Comment: @GitGud Good! The matter was of the highest importance... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the area of your integration. Horizontal is $x$ and vertical is $y$.

[image]

So if you change to integrate over $x$ first, there is a small trick when $y$ goes below $0$.

if $y>0$, the integral limit is simply $-2\sqrt{y+1}<x<2-y$

if $y<0$, the integral limit is $-2\sqrt{y+1}<x<2\sqrt{y+1}$

So in all, your integral can be written as

$$
\int_0^8 dy \int_{-2\sqrt{y+1}}^{2-y} f(x)dx + \int_{-1}^0 dy \int_{-2\sqrt{y+1}}^{2\sqrt{y+1}}f(x)dx
$$

or in a more succinct form,
$$
\int_{-1}^8 dy \int_{-2\sqrt{y+1}}^{\min(2\sqrt{y+1},2-y)} f(x)dx
$$